# why is the build working for ios but not android? React native

Tags: android, react-native

I just created a new project with react native, I downloaded homebrew, Android Studio, and Watchman but I still cant build my project on the virtual device. It works on IOS from the moment the project was created but not Android.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/cal/Solvicles/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up
```

Answer (score 0):

According from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started):

Have you tried adding the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to `$HOME/.bash_profile`? If not, go ahead and add it to your `.bash_profile` (or create if the file doesn't exists) in your home `~` directory.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Then restart the terminal and try to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your environment is setup properly for android, go to the root of your react-native project. Open the android project(folder) in the Android Studio IDE.

All errors with your environment will show up, and that will automatically start the Gradle Daemon to sync and configure the build for you. Once it finished, close the Android Studio and come back to command-line and run: `react-native run-android`

And dont forget to execute below thingsfor android home path variable :

The React Native tools require some environment variables to be set up in order to build apps with native code.

**Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc config file:**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

> .bash_profile is specific to bash. If you're using another shell, you
>   will need to edit the appropriate shell-specific config file.

Type source $HOME/.bash_profile to load the config into your current shell. Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been added to your path by running echo $PATH.

Please make sure you use the correct Android SDK path. You can find the actual location of the SDK in the Android Studio "Preferences" dialog, under Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK.

Hope it helps.